# Stream from ffmpeg with seeking

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have a complex ffmpeg command that generates video from several static sources.  I would like to be able to seek forward and backward through the output without waiting for the whole file to be generated.  That way, I can check that it's going to come out right without waiting so long.  Is that possible with streaming?

I've managed to stream the output with the following command, but when I connect to the resulting stream using ffplay, seeking is unreliable.  I'm able to move forward and backward a little bit, but the audio-video sync is frequently off and the video often stops playing or goes into slow motion.  Is there something else I need to do in order to make this work smoothly?

Thanks.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg \
  -ss 161.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 182.9 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 265.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 2982.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 2959 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2965 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2970 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3023 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3056.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3074.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3051 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3088 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3121.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3231.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3236.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3333.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3338.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3472.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3449 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3455 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3488.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3656.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3633 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3641 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3674.4 \
  -t 4 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3650 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3666 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3699.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 3741.4 \
  -t 5 \
  -i mono.m4a \
  -ss 133 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 154.5 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 200 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 237 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2917 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 2954 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2922 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 2959 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2928 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 2965 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2970 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2933 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3023 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2986 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3028 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 2991 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3046 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3009 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3051 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3014 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3088 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3051 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3093 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3056 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3203 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3166 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3171 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3208 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3268 \
  -t 5 \
  -i Encode_1080P_35.mp4 \
  -ss 3305 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3310 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3444 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3449 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3455 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3460 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3628 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3633 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3641 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3646 \
  -t 4 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3650 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3666 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3671 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -ss 3713 \
  -t 5 \
  -i 0-1.mov \
  -framerate 29.97002997002997 \
  -loop 1 \
  -i biolisp_logo.png \
  -filter_complex "[text-overlay-4][0:0][text-overlay-7][1:0][text-overlay-15][2:0][text-overlay-23][3:0][text-overlay-31][4:0][text-overlay-39][5:0][text-overlay-47][6:0][text-overlay-55][7:0][text-overlay-63][8:0][text-overlay-71][9:0][text-overlay-79][10:0][text-overlay-87][11:0][text-overlay-95][12:0][text-overlay-103][13:0][text-overlay-111][14:0][text-overlay-119][15:0][text-overlay-122][16:0][text-overlay-125][17:0][text-overlay-128][18:0][text-overlay-131][19:0][text-overlay-134][20:0][text-overlay-137][21:0][text-overlay-140][22:0][text-overlay-143][23:0][text-overlay-146][24:0][text-overlay-149][25:0][text-overlay-152][26:0][text-overlay-155][27:0][text-overlay-158][28:0] concat=n=29:v=1:a=1 [concat-video-0][concat-audio-1]; [29:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-2]; [change-fps-2] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-3]; [scale-3] drawtext=text='ms cv 2m13s-2.m39.5s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:02\\\\:13\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-4]; [30:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-5]; [change-fps-5] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-6]; [scale-6] drawtext=text='ms cv 2m13s-2.m39.5s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:02\\\\:34\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-7]; [31:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-8]; [change-fps-8] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-9]; [32:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-10]; [crop-10] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-11]; [scale-9][scale-11] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-12]; [overlay-top-right-12] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-13]; [change-fps-13] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-14]; [scale-14] drawtext=text='ms p 3m57s-49m19s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:03\\\\:57\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-15]; [33:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-16]; [change-fps-16] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-17]; [34:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-18]; [crop-18] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-19]; [scale-17][scale-19] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-20]; [overlay-top-right-20] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-21]; [change-fps-21] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-22]; [scale-22] drawtext=text='ms p 3m57s-49m19s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:49\\\\:14\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-23]; [35:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-24]; [change-fps-24] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-25]; [36:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-26]; [crop-26] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-27]; [scale-25][scale-27] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-28]; [overlay-top-right-28] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-29]; [change-fps-29] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-30]; [scale-30] drawtext=text='ca p 49m19s-49m30s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:49\\\\:19\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-31]; [37:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-32]; [change-fps-32] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-33]; [38:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-34]; [crop-34] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-35]; [scale-33][scale-35] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-36]; [overlay-top-right-36] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-37]; [change-fps-37] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-38]; [scale-38] drawtext=text='ca p 49m19s-49m30s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:49\\\\:25\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-39]; [39:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-40]; [change-fps-40] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-41]; [40:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-42]; [crop-42] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-43]; [scale-41][scale-43] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-44]; [overlay-top-right-44] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-45]; [change-fps-45] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-46]; [scale-46] drawtext=text='ca pinv 49m30s-50m28s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:49\\\\:30\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-47]; [41:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-48]; [change-fps-48] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-49]; [42:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-50]; [crop-50] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-51]; [scale-49][scale-51] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-52]; [overlay-top-right-52] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-53]; [change-fps-53] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-54]; [scale-54] drawtext=text='ca pinv 49m30s-50m28s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:50\\\\:23\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-55]; [43:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-56]; [change-fps-56] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-57]; [44:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-58]; [crop-58] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-59]; [scale-57][scale-59] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-60]; [overlay-top-right-60] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-61]; [change-fps-61] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-62]; [scale-62] drawtext=text='ms pinv 50m28s-50m51s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:50\\\\:28\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-63]; [45:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-64]; [change-fps-64] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-65]; [46:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-66]; [crop-66] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-67]; [scale-65][scale-67] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-68]; [overlay-top-right-68] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-69]; [change-fps-69] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-70]; [scale-70] drawtext=text='ms pinv 50m28s-50m51s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:50\\\\:46\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-71]; [47:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-72]; [change-fps-72] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-73]; [48:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-74]; [crop-74] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-75]; [scale-73][scale-75] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-76]; [overlay-top-right-76] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-77]; [change-fps-77] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-78]; [scale-78] drawtext=text='ca pinv 50m51s-51m33s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:50\\\\:51\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-79]; [49:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-80]; [change-fps-80] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-81]; [50:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-82]; [crop-82] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-83]; [scale-81][scale-83] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-84]; [overlay-top-right-84] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-85]; [change-fps-85] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-86]; [scale-86] drawtext=text='ca pinv 50m51s-51m33s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:51\\\\:28\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-87]; [51:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-88]; [change-fps-88] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-89]; [52:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-90]; [crop-90] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-91]; [scale-89][scale-91] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-92]; [overlay-top-right-92] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-93]; [change-fps-93] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-94]; [scale-94] drawtext=text='ms pinv 51m33s-53m28s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:51\\\\:33\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-95]; [53:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-96]; [change-fps-96] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-97]; [54:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-98]; [crop-98] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-99]; [scale-97][scale-99] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-100]; [overlay-top-right-100] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-101]; [change-fps-101] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-102]; [scale-102] drawtext=text='ms pinv 51m33s-53m28s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:53\\\\:23\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-103]; [55:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-104]; [change-fps-104] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-105]; [56:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-106]; [crop-106] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-107]; [scale-105][scale-107] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-108]; [overlay-top-right-108] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-109]; [change-fps-109] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-110]; [scale-110] drawtext=text='ms p 53m28s-55m10s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:53\\\\:28\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-111]; [57:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-112]; [change-fps-112] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-113]; [58:1] crop=w=in_w*.9:h=in_h*.9:x=in_w*0.:y=in_h*0. [crop-114]; [crop-114] scale=w=384.:h=216. [scale-115]; [scale-113][scale-115] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:0:shortest=1 [overlay-top-right-116]; [overlay-top-right-116] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-117]; [change-fps-117] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-118]; [scale-118] drawtext=text='ms p 53m28s-55m10s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:55\\\\:05\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-119]; [59:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-120]; [change-fps-120] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-121]; [scale-121] drawtext=text='ms cv 55m10s-57m29s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:55\\\\:10\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-122]; [60:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-123]; [change-fps-123] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-124]; [scale-124] drawtext=text='ms cv 55m10s-57m29s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:57\\\\:24\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-125]; [61:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-126]; [change-fps-126] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-127]; [scale-127] drawtext=text='ca cv 57m29s-57m40s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:57\\\\:29\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-128]; [62:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-129]; [change-fps-129] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-130]; [scale-130] drawtext=text='ca cv 57m29s-57m40s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:57\\\\:35\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-131]; [63:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-132]; [change-fps-132] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-133]; [scale-133] drawtext=text='ms cv 57m40s-1h0m33s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=00\\\\:57\\\\:40\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-134]; [64:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-135]; [change-fps-135] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-136]; [scale-136] drawtext=text='ms cv 57m40s-1h0m33s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:00\\\\:28\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-137]; [65:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-138]; [change-fps-138] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-139]; [scale-139] drawtext=text='ca cv 1h0m33s-1h0m46s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:00\\\\:33\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-140]; [66:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-141]; [change-fps-141] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-142]; [scale-142] drawtext=text='ca cv 1h0m33s-1h0m46s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:00\\\\:41\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-143]; [67:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-144]; [change-fps-144] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-145]; [scale-145] drawtext=text='ms cv 1h0m46s-1h0m50s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:00\\\\:46\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-146]; [68:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-147]; [change-fps-147] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-148]; [scale-148] drawtext=text='ca cv 1h0m50s-1h1m11s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:00\\\\:50\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-149]; [69:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-150]; [change-fps-150] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-151]; [scale-151] drawtext=text='ca cv 1h0m50s-1h1m11s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:01\\\\:06\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-152]; [70:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-153]; [change-fps-153] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-154]; [scale-154] drawtext=text='ms cv 1h1m11s-1h1m58s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:01\\\\:11\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-155]; [71:1] fps=29.97002997002997 [change-fps-156]; [change-fps-156] scale=w=1920:h=1080 [scale-157]; [scale-157] drawtext=text='ms cv 1h1m11s-1h1m58s\\ ':borderw=5:expansion=strftime:font=DroidSans:fontcolor=white:fontsize=36:rate=30000/1001:timecode=01\\\\:01\\\\:53\\\\:00:x=(main_w-tw)/2:y=main_h-th [text-overlay-158]; [72:v] fade=out:st=15:d=1:alpha=1 [fade-out-159]; [concat-video-0][fade-out-159] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-50:main_h-overlay_h-50:shortest=1 [overlay-watermark-160]" \
  -strict -2 \
  -map [overlay-watermark-160] \
  -map [concat-audio-1] \
  -codec:a aac \
  -codec:v libx264 \
  -preset ultrafast \
  -tune zerolatency \
  -y \
  -f mpegts \
  udp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Comment: Happy new year!  Is there any way to make this work?  <ffmpeg> is so powerful that I hope that it is, but I just can't figure out how to make it work smoothly.